# C++ object does not save variable values

Tags: c++, c++11

I am a beginner C++ programmer and currently trying to modify an existing C++ project to be more flexible. A communication from a raspberry pi hat to sensors should be established:

Communication.cpp

```
 vector<PortMax> ports;
 void Communication::Communication_setup() {
    // Create hardware setup
    hardware = HardwareRaspberry();
    hardware.begin();

    // Create drivers
    Max *pDriver01 = new Max(DRIVER01, &hardware);
    Max *pDriver23 = new Max(DRIVER23, &hardware);
    // Create ports
    ports.push_back(PortMax(pDriver01, PORT0PORT));
    ports.push_back(PortMax(pDriver01, PORT1PORT));
    // Start communication
    for(auto nr: ports) {
        nr.begin();
    }

uint8_t Communication::getSequence(int port_nr) {
     uint8_t retVal = ports.at(port_nr).getSequencePort();
}
```

PortMax.cpp

```
void PortMax::begin() {
     uint8_t pData[3];
     readDirectParameterPage(0x03, pData);
     mSequenceType_ = uint8_t((pData[0] >> 1) & 0x07);
     cout << "MSequenceType: " << mSequenceType_ << endl;
}
uint8_t PortMax::getSequencePort() {
     return mSequenceType_;
}
```

PortMax.h

```
class PortMax {
     uint8_t mSequenceType_ = 0;
     void begin();
     uint8_t getSequencePort();
}
```

I have the problem that my variable (in this case mSequenceType_) is saved correctly under the name when the connection is established and also shows the correct value at cout. But as soon as I jump out of the begin() function and want to get the mSequenceType_ from port0 with getSequence() only the initial value is returned.
For this reason I think that my variable is only assigned locally and not for my whole object. Do you see what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
for(auto nr: ports) {
    nr.begin();
}
```

makes a copy of each entry in `ports`. `nr` is a PortMax variable, not a reference to the PortMax in the vector.

Add `&` to make it a reference. Now you are calling `begin` on the PortMax objects in the vector.

```
//      v
for(auto& nr: ports) {
    nr.begin();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Now my code works.